# Что означает данный код

Tags: javascript

Дали дз разобрать данный код.

```js
"use strict"
var ar = new Array(1, 2, 3);
ar.myProp = "Dewewewemo";
alert(ar.myProp);
alert(ar["myProp"]);
var nam = "myProp";
alert(ar[nam]);
alert(ar[0]);
```

Comment: Какая строчка вызывает затруднения?

Answer (score 4):

1. `"use strict"` - перевод выполнения в [строгий режим](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)
2. `var ar = new Array(1, 2, 3);` - объявление [массива с тремя элементами](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Array)
3. `ar.myProp = "Dewewewemo";` - добавление объявленному массиву свойства с именем `myProp`
4. `alert(ar.myProp);` - вывод с помощью функции [`alert`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert) значения свойства с именем `myProp`. Обращение к свойству происходит с помощью [точечной нотации](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Dot_notation)
5. `alert(ar["myProp"]);` - вывод с помощью функции [`alert`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert) значения свойства с именем `myProp`. Обращение к свойству происходит с помощью [скобочной нотации](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation)
6. `var nam = "myProp";` - объявление переменной `nam` и присваивание ей значения `"myProp"`
7. `alert(ar[nam]);` - вывод с помощью функции [`alert`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert) значения свойства с именем `myProp` взятого из переменной `nam`. Обращение к свойству происходит с помощью [скобочной нотации](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation)
8. `alert(ar[0]);` - вывод с помощью функции [`alert`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert) значения нулевого элемента массива. Обращение к элементу происходит с помощью [скобочной нотации](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation)